# Using docker compose, is there a way of re-using *multiple* groups of top level defined variables in multiple service definitions?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm using docker-compose to spin up multiple services on my local machine to replicate a hosted environment. As such, I have a lot of repetition in these services that is common across them all. This includes logging, connection strings, some communication constants and so on. As I understand it, I can group all of my variables together in one massive clump at the top as follows:

```
version: "3.9"

x-logging:
  &logging
  Logging__LogLevel__Default:Information


services:
  api1:
    build: ..
    ports:
    - "8001:443"
    environment:
      <<: *logging
    volumes:
      - .:/code
 api2:
    ports:
    - "8002:443"
    environment:
      <<: *logging
 api3:
    ports:
    - "8003:443"
    environment:
      <<: *logging
```

And so on and so forth. However, it would be nice if I can add further blocks that could be concatenated together like this:

```
version: "3.9"

x-logging:
  &logging
  Logging__LogLevel__Default:Information

x-database:
  &database
   ConnectionStrings__MyDatabase:Server=host.docker.internal\\sqlexpress;Database=mydb;

services:
  api1:
    build: ..
    ports:
    - "8001:443"
    environment:
      <<: *logging
      <<: *database ****** This is not permitted ******
    volumes:
      - .:/code
 api2:
    ports:
    - "8002:443"
    environment:
      <<: *logging
 api3:
    ports:
    - "8003:443"
    environment:
      <<: *logging
      <<: *database* ****** This is not permitted ******
```

Is there anything like this supported? I know I could just bundle all of the variables together at the top, but that feels like it would get confusing quickly for a complicated product. All examples I've seen in Docker Compose only show a single set of variables being concatenated and then extended with one or two more additional local variables. Doesn't strike me as very DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question raises the issue of "merging" several environment variables together, only defined once.

It happens environment variables in `docker-compose.yml` can be defined both:

- in terms of maps, e.g.

  ```yaml
  environment:
    VAR1: 'Value 1'
    VAR2: 'Value 2'
  ```
- or in terms of sequences of `=`–strings, e.g.:

  ```yaml
  environment:
    - 'VAR1=Value 1'
    - 'VAR2=Value 2'
  ```

The YAML standard does not allow merging sequences (there is an [open issue](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/48) for that).

But merging maps do work!

### Solution 1

(*works with docker-compose, but **not YAML-compliant** because of multiple `<<`*)

```yaml
x-logging:
  &logging
  Logging__LogLevel__Default: Information

x-database:
  &database
  ConnectionStrings__MyDatabase: Server=host.docker.internal\\sqlexpress;Database=mydb;

services:
  api1:
    build: ..
    ports:
    - "8001:443"
    environment:
      <<: *logging
      <<: *database
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

#### Solution 2 (recommended)

(*YAML 1.1 compliant, cf. [spec](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html)*)

```yaml
x-logging:
  &logging
  Logging__LogLevel__Default: Information

x-database:
  &database
  ConnectionStrings__MyDatabase: Server=host.docker.internal\\sqlexpress;Database=mydb;

services:
  api1:
    build: ..
    ports:
    - "8001:443"
    environment:
      <<: [*logging, *database]
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

#### Solution 3 (less powerful, but might be handy)

(*does not support overriding*)

```yaml
x-logging:
  &logging
  Logging__LogLevel__Default=Information

x-database:
  &database
  ConnectionStrings__MyDatabase=Server=host.docker.internal\\sqlexpress;Database=mydb;

services:
  api1:
    build: ..
    ports:
    - "8001:443"
    environment:
      - *database
      - *logging
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

#### Remarks

1. It appears the only missing bit in your minimal example was a SPACE after the `:` character.
2. To do a "dry-run" and test whether the YAML file is supported without running the containers, just run [`docker compose config`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_config/).

Comment: @TheSenator did you try the suggestions above? just to know if this worked for you.

Comment: just noticed your response. I'll try this out first thing and report back! Thank you in advance

Comment: Solution 2 seems to be a winner, no complaints from the linting. I found that Solution 1 (adding the missing spaces didn't seem to improve the linting without also the [brackets merge] approach). Empty sequences also upset it (but that's just for information). Amazing that that single space changes the meaning so much in this file. This is brilliant thank you!